# How can i detect the Forms Previewer mode?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Visual Studio 2017 introduces a new window to help with mobile development - The "Forms Previewer"-window.

Has anyone found out how to detect this mode yet?

I have some telemetry code, which throws exceptions because it is not initialized yet - hence the need to detect this "design" mode.

Answer (score 4):

Now Xamarin.Forms supports this directly and you can use its built in `Xamarin.Forms.DesignMode` class:

```
if (DesignMode.IsDesignModeEnabled)
{
  // Previewer only code  
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer

Answer (score 1):

Previously it was possible to detect design mode if the app instance is not created, like this:

```
if (Application.Current==null) 
{  
    // design mode
}
```

In Xamarin Studio 6.2 the app instance is created even in design mode, so we can't use it like that. What you can do is creating your custom flag IsInDesignMode = true and change it to false from place which is not run in design mode, like OnStart:

```
protected override void OnStart()
{
    FakeViewModels.IsInDesignMode = false;
}
```

and then use it wherever you want:

```
if (FakeViewModels.IsInDesignMode == false) 
{
    this.BindingContext = this;
}
```

Also remember that App() constructor and therefore first navigation happens before OnStart(), so using above method is not going to cover the first page you'll navigate to.